# Is it always true that $-\int_{\mathbb{R}} \log p(Y|\theta)v(\theta)d\theta \geq 0$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Is it always true that -$\int_{\mathbb{R}} \log[p(Y|\theta)]v(\theta)d\theta \geq 0$ where $p(Y|\theta)$ is the likelihood for data $Y$ and $v(\theta)$ is any prior distribution? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For the case when $Y$ is not discrete, this expectation can be negative. Let for simplicity $Y$ is a single r.v. with PDF $p(y|\theta)=\theta e^{-\theta y}$ for $y>0$, $P(\theta=1)=P(\theta=4)=1/2$.

Let also observed $Y=1/4$.
Then $-\log p(y|\theta)=-\log(\theta)+\theta y=-\log \theta+\dfrac{\theta}4$,
$$
E\left(-\log\theta+\dfrac{\theta}4\right)=\dfrac12\left(-\log 1+\dfrac14\right)+\dfrac12\left(-\log 4+1\right)=\dfrac58-\log 2\approx -0.068 < 0.
$$

Answer (score 0):

If $Y$ is discrete, you can use Jensen's inequality and the fact that $P(Y) \le 1$:
\begin{align*}
\int_{\mathbb{R}} -\log[p(Y|\theta)]v(\theta)d\theta  &\ge - \log \int_{\mathbb{R}}p(Y|\theta)\nu(\theta)d\theta \\
&= -\log p(Y) \\
&\ge 0.
\end{align*}

Otherwise I'm not sure.